# How to detect whether a set of two values exist in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `ProductCustomer`
which contains two fields: `ProductID` and `CustomerID` 

It represents which customer bought which product

Lets assume it has the following data:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| ProductID |  CustomerID |
+-----------+-------------+
|     17    |     105     |
|      8    |     201     |
|     17    |     123     |
|      9    |      36     |
|      5    |     950     |
|     14    |     204     |
|      8    |     116     |
|     39    |     105     |
+-----------+-------------+
```

I want to detect by one query whether products with ids `17`, `8`, `12` and `39` were bought by customer with id `105`. 
 i.e. the query takes list `(17, 8, 12, 39)` and value `105` as parameters, and the result should be:

```
+-----------+----------+
| ProductID | isBought |
+-----------+----------+
|     17    |     1    | ---> Bought twice, once by CutomerId 105
|      8    |     0    | ---> Bought twice, none of them by CutomerId 105
|     12    |     0    | ---> Was not bought ever by any customer
|     39    |     1    | ---> Bought once, which was by CutomerId 105
+-----------+----------+
```

Which query could help me to deduce this result set ?

I am using MySQL if this matters.

---

**UPDATE: Product table exists in another schema with other privileges. I cannot use it in current query.**

Comment: So there's also a table of products, which contains all product ids?

Comment: You need a table that contains the `ProductID`s that are missing from this table, in order to select them from somewhere. Generating data out of nowhere is an easy job with other `RDBMS`-es but is not quite a job to perform with MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** added a query that gets the desired results without needing any extra coding on the client side.

#### The original answer

Sub-queries and `GROUP BY` are too much work for such a simple task.

This query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProductID
FROM Product_Customer
WHERE ProductID IN (17, 8, 12, 39)
  AND CustomerID = 105
```

returns you the list of `ProductID`s that were bought by the customer - the rows with `1` in the column `isBought` of your desired outcome.

Use several lines of code on the client language to fill the rest: create a list containing all the input products and initialize the elements' `isBought` property with zero. Run the query. Set the value `1` for products returned be the query.

For example, using PHP it will look like this:

```
// Input data
$productIDs = array(17, 8, 12, 39);
$customerID = 105;

// Prepare the list of products indexed by ProductID
// None of them was bought by the customer yet (this is all the information
// we have at this point; it will be updated below)
$list = array_fill_keys($productIDs, 0);

// Run the query
// Assume we already have a PDO connection in $db
// In production code you should protect the query against injection
// using either quoting or, better, prepared statements.
$result = $db->query(
    'SELECT ProductID '.
    'FROM Product_Customer '.
    'WHERE ProductID IN ('.implode($productIDs).') '.
        'AND CustomerID = '.$customerID
);

// Get the values
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $prodID = intval($row['ProductID']);
    // Mark the product as bought
    $list[$prodID] = 1;
}

// Dump $list to check the outcome
print_r($list);
```

#### Update

The desired result can be retrieved directly from the database by `JOIN`-ing the table `Products` (the table where the `FK` `ProductID came from):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ProductID, IF(pc.ProductID IS NULL, 0, 1) AS isBought
FROM Product_Customer pc
  RIGHT JOIN Products p ON pc.ProductID = p.ProductID AND pc.CustomerID = 105
WHERE p.ProductID IN (17, 8, 12, 39)
```

If the table `Products` is not available (the OP added this extra condition in the question) then a result set containing all the desired `ProductID`s needs to be generated somehow out of nowhere.

One possibility is to `SELECT` each value in a separate query and `UNION` them:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ProductID, IF(pc.ProductID IS NULL, 0, 1) AS isBought
FROM Product_Customer pc
  RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT 17 AS ProductID
    UNION
    SELECT 8 AS ProductID
    UNION
    SELECT 12 AS ProductID
    UNION
    SELECT 39 AS ProductID
  ) p ON pc.ProductID = p.ProductID AND pc.CustomerID = 105
```

We don't need the `WHERE` condition any more because the fake `Products` table we generated on-the-fly (using `UNION`) contains only the desired values for `ProductID` and nothing else).

It is not slower than the original query (see the first query, the one that returns only the products that exist in the `Product_Customer` table) and I think it is faster than the one that `JOIN`s the real `Products` table.

---

Another solution (more esoteric but working) is revealed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28609094/4265352).

Comment: Yeah, I think this is a reasonable approach if application code is available.

Comment: But I don't consider this less work. It is *more* work for the programmer,  *more* work for the application, and *more* work for the network. But admittedly *less* work for the DBMS.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner It's *less* work for the network. It's a single column and only a subset of the expected rows. The amount of additional work for the programmer depends a lot on the client language. A scripting language usually can create the needed data structure and fill it with zeroes in just 1 line of code (the call to function `array_fill_keys()` in my PHP code above). The rest of the code is already there anyway, ready to get and process the result set received from the DB. Putting them together, client application and database, the big total is *less* work.

Comment: @axiac. Consider daily purchases where a client bought the products thousands of times. Instead of retrieving four records, you are retrieving thousands from the database. This is what I consider more work for the network. As to the application: yes that depends on the language used. In C# for instance I could just fill a dataset with the result set with two lines of code or go the hard way to fill a dataset manually in a loop.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Well, the thousands of times issue can be solved by adding `DISTINCT` to the query (I updated the answer). The OP doesn't ask to get the number of times a customer bought a product and from the information in the question I assumed each (ProductID, CustomerID) combination appears only once in the table (that's why I didn't use `DISTINCT` from the beginning).

Comment: @axiac: Ah, that is somthing I didn't see. You are right; it's not about counting but about whether or not. I misread the request and you may be right with that one-entry theory :-)

Comment: @axiac , Isn't there any other solution without using code, even if it is worse in performance ?

Comment: @AshrafBashir I updated the answer with another query (in fact, two queries) that gets the desired resultset directly from the database, without needing extra coding on the client side. If the `Products` table is not accessible then I suggested an alternative query that might become pretty lengthy when the list of input products increases (but I think it is not slower than the original query).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following: ([**Working SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/820eec/2))

```
SELECT 
    ProductID, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ProductCustomer AS p2 WHERE CustomerID=105 AND p1.ProductID=p2.ProductID) AS isBought 
FROM Product AS p1 
WHERE ProductID IN (17, 8, 12, 39)
```

Comment: Product table exists in another schema with other privileges. I cannot use it in current query

Comment: @AshrafBashir then you can only find the rows that have been purchased.  In your example product number 12 will not show in the result. just replace `FROM Product AS p1 ` with `FROM ProductCustomer AS p1 `

Comment: I didn't ! ... Is there something wrong in the system that attached my name to any downvote ?!! I cannot even see my name beside downvotes

Comment: @AshrafBashir Did replacing `FROM Product AS p1` with `FROM ProductCustomer AS p1` fix you problem?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customer;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product_customer;

CREATE TABLE product
(product_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE customer
(customer_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE product_customer
(product_id INT NOT NULL
,customer_id INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(product_id,customer_id)
);

INSERT INTO product VALUES
(5),(8),(9),(14),(12),(17),(39);

INSERT INTO customer VALUES
(36),
(105),
(201),
(123),
(950),
(204),
(116);

INSERT INTO product_customer VALUES
(17    ,105),
(8     ,201),
(17    ,123),
(9     , 36),
(5     ,950),
(14    ,204),
(8     ,116),
(39    ,105);

SELECT p.*
     , MAX(CASE WHEN c.customer_id = 105 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) isbought 
  FROM product p 
  LEFT 
  JOIN product_customer pc 
    ON pc.product_id = p.product_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN customer c 
    ON c.customer_id = pc.customer_id 
 WHERE p.product_id IN(17,8,12,39)
 GROUP 
    BY p.product_id;
+------------+----------+
| product_id | isbought |
+------------+----------+
|          8 |        0 |
|         12 |        0 |
|         17 |        1 |
|         39 |        1 |
+------------+----------+
```

Comment: +1 FOR BEING RIGHT! :)
I've also updated my answer to support this.

Comment: why did you use joins here?

Comment: @YotamOmer Um, why not? If performance is the issue, then I suspect axiac's solution will trounce both yours and mine ;-)

Comment: Product table exists in another schema with other privileges. I cannot use it in current query

Answer (score 0):

As not all products exist in table ProductCustomer, you must select from table Product instead to get a result record per requested product.

As you want to now whether a record *exists* in table ProductCustomer, you should use EXISTS obviously.

```
select 
  productid, 
  exists 
  (
    select * from productcustomer pc 
    where pc.productid = p.productid and pc.customerid = 105
  ) as isbought
from product p
where productid in (17, 8, 12, 39);
```

Update: As you cannot access the product table, you must generate the records to show. For instance:

```
select 
  productid, 
  exists 
  (
    select * from productcustomer pc 
    where pc.productid = p.productid and pc.customerid = 105
  ) as isbought
from 
(
  select 17 as productid union all 
  select 8               union all 
  select 12              union all  
  select 39
) p;
```

Comment: I misread your question and thought you wanted to count records. I have altered my answer now to match your request.

Comment: Product table exists in another schema with other privileges. I cannot use it in current query

Comment: Okay, You need a record per requested product ID. There are several ways to do this. One is to select row numbers from a big enough table and get the desired numbers from those. Or find a table that is guaranteed to hold all product numbers and retrieve the numbers wanted with WHERE and DISTINCT. Or use UNION ALL, as I am showing in my updated answer. Or retrieve only existing records from ProductCustomer and fill the missing IDs in your application.

Answer (score 0):

The following deals with the fact that product #12 does not exist in the table, but assumes that your table has already some rows...

```
  SET @a:=0.5;
  SELECT @b:=MAKE_SET(@a:=@a*2, 17,8,12,39) ProductID,
     IFNULL((SELECT 1 FROM mytable2
     WHERE ProductID=@b AND CustomerID=105 LIMIT 1), 0) isBought
     FROM mytable2 m1
     LIMIT 4;

 +-----------+----------+
 | ProductID | isBought |
 +-----------+----------+
 | 17        |        1 |
 | 8         |        0 |
 | 12        |        0 |
 | 39        |        1 |
 +-----------+----------+
```

Of course if you have a product table you just have to do:

```
 SELECT p.ProductID, IFNULL((SELECT 1 FROM mytable2
    WHERE ProductID=p.ProductID AND CustomerID=105 LIMIT 1), 0) isBought
 FROM Products p
 WHERE p.ProductID IN(17,8,12,39);
```

Comment: Product table exists in another schema with other privileges. I cannot use it in current query

Comment: ok so the first one will make the job but it would have been easier not to report elements with 0 bought item

Answer (score -1):

GROUP BY, use SUM with case to count

```
select ProductID, sum(case when CustomerID = 105 then 1 else 0 end)
from tablename
where ProductID in (17, 8, 12, 39)
group by ProductID
```

Comment: This doesn't give the proper output. It skips products that were never bought by any customer (product 12 in example)

Comment: @YotamOmer. Very odd, it selects all rows with ProductID in (17, 8, 12, 39), and counts the number of rows where CustomerID = 105.

Comment: @jarlh: Not odd at all. There is yet no record for product 12 in ProductCustomer.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, now I see! (Didn't notice that product# didn't exist.)